# supress of displaying username and password in JNLP console

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

After Installing java 7 (1.7.21) from java 6.0, I have observed some properties displayed like username, password and other information in JNLP console (Java Web Start 10.21.2.11). This problem didn't occur in java 1.6. Could anyone suggest a solution for avoiding display of username and password from JNLP console?

**Stack Trace:**

```
Java Web Start 10.21.2.11
Using JRE version 1.7.0_21-b11 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
p:   reload proxy configuration
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
CacheEntry[file://localhost/...sample.pl.jnlp]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Fri Jun 21 12:27:03 IST 2013,length=4696
    Match: beginTraversal
Match: digest selected JREDesc: JREDesc[version 1.4+, heap=-1--1, args=null, href=http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se, sel=false, null, null], JREInfo: JREInfo for index 0:
    platform is: 1.7
    product is: 1.7.0_21
    location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
    path is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    args is: 
    native platform is: Windows, x86 [ x86, 32bit ]
    JavaFX runtime is: JavaFX 2.2.21 found at C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\
    enabled is: true
    registered is: false
    system is: true

    Match: ignoring maxHeap: -1
    Match: ignoring InitHeap: -1
    Match: digesting vmargs: null
    Match: digested vmargs: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: JVM args after accumulation: [JVMParameters: isSecure: true, args: ]
    Match: digest LaunchDesc: file://localhost/D:/...sample.pl.jnlp
    Match: digest properties: **[-Djnlp.test.userName=username, -Djnlp.test.password=password, -Djnlp.test.defaultHost=....,** -Djnlp.test.userName=username-Djnlp.test.password=pwd-...
```